# Removing spaces between anchor tags

Tags: html, css

I am working on a navigation links, there is a some gaps in between the links. 
Got some solution for earlier questions from stackoverflow which says to remove the whitespaces between anchor tags as some browser will treat them as newline.  In my case there are no spaces between thee anchor tags.

[enter link description here](http://postimg.org/image/e2rsaam7b/)

```
         <div id="nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="link1">Link1</a></li>
                <li><a href="link2">Link2</a></li>
                <li><a href="link3">Link3</a></li>
            </ul>
         </div>

#nav{
  background-color:#000000; 
}


#nav ul {
  height: 50px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-align:center;
  border:1px solid #fff; 
}

#nav ul li { 
   display: inline-block; 
   height: 50px;
   width: 150px; 
   text-align: center; 
   border-right:1px solid #fff;
   border-left:1px solid #fff;
   list-style: none; 
   font: normal bold 12px/1.2em Arial, Verdana, Helvetica;
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
   background-color: #000000;
}


 #nav ul li a{
   padding: 18px 0; 
   text-decoration: none; 
   color: white; 
   display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick solution would be to use `float: left` instead of `display: inline-block` for `#nav ul li`. Here's a complete **[article](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/)** on how to remove the white space between `inline-block` elements using various methods.

By the way, the white space between each menu item which you see now is because of the `border-right` and the `border-left`.

```css
#nav{
  background-color:#000000; 
}


#nav ul {
  height: 50px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-align:center;
  border:1px solid #fff; 
}

#nav ul li { 
   float: left; 
   height: 50px;
   width: 150px; 
   text-align: center; 
   border-right:1px solid #fff;
   border-left:1px solid #fff;
   list-style: none; 
   font: normal bold 12px/1.2em Arial, Verdana, Helvetica;
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
   background-color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="link1">Link1</a></li>
                <li><a href="link2">Link2</a></li>
                <li><a href="link3">Link3</a></li>
            </ul>
         </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have whitespaces in the anchor tags but you do have in the li tags. The li tags are the ones with `inline-block`. You should either remove those as well, or use `font-size: 0;` on the ul tag and then reset to the correct `font-size` in the li tag.

You should think of `inline-block` elements as really big characters, that way you can understand them easier.

Answer (score 0):

font-size: 0 should be an answer!. In my case I make div including anchor tags.
After putting font-size: 0 on div, the space between anchor tags.